# Android Different shapes for painting application

Tags: android, canvas, paint

i want to make a painting application where i want to give options to the user to select a pattern for painting similar to "**Infinite Painter APP**" in Google-play. can you help me out in designing different patterns for painting in android app. i searched a lot in Google  and i found the following link
http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-tutorial/shape-drawing-example-in-android/
and i don't know how to put these patterns as an option for user to paint on the view as he moves his finger on the screen.

can any one suggest me how to do this in android. and also  good tutorials for painting application or any open source project links to learn.

**Screenshot for reference:**

[image]

help me with a better solution.

Comment: the example you linked seems quite good, what's the problem?

Comment: how to paint that patterns on the screen while touching

Answer (score -1):

I know beginner android developers wish to make advance android apps like "MS Paint" for example ,but due to lack of coding Knowledge some tasks might take time do accomplish. I can help you doing what you need :

1. Create a new class in your project's src file
   name it a List.java
2. Create a new xml file name it listactivty.xml
3. in your List.java class within OnCreate Method type setContentView(R.layout.listactivity);
4. go to your xml file and frm pallete drag Scroll View frm Composite onto your layout.
5. Whatever your list of paintbrushes (Option) contain put it under scrool View in xml file

Example:

```
     <ScrollView....>

      <ImageButton1.../>

       <ImageButton2.../>

       <ImageButton3.../>

       </ScrollView>
```

6.Create an Intent for List.java class to open In previous class and with the help of that intent activated On Click of a Button named Options you can open listactivity.xml layout and you will see options of ImageButtons 1,2 and 3 in vertical and scroll them vetically and Choose options.

Some Help with Scroll View go to this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNX996ZZ2CI